# Overriding Sharepoint 2013 Web Parts in VS 2012

Tags: web-part, visual-studio-2012, content-search-web-part

I'd like to override Content Search Web Part (SharePoint 2013) and I found following articles on this subject

- [Dev Help: SharePoint 2013 Content Search Web Part (CSWP) in Variation Sites](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2013/08/sharepoint-2013-content-search-web-part.html)
- [SharePoint 2013 : Set Content Search Web Part “QueryText” Attribute Programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidrei/archive/2012/12/27/sharepoint-2013-set-content-search-web-part-querytext-attribute-programmatically.aspx)

However, problem is I'm not quite sure how it could be done. I've created Empty SharePoint Project and added both class to it (.cs file) and references Microsoft.Office.Server.Search and System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts (and, of course, reference them to the file by key word using).
However, I can't expose class ContentBySearchWebPart (to override it).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search;

namespace SharePointProject
{

    public class CustomCSWP : ContentBySearchWebPart
    {
    }
}
```

ContentBySearchWebPart has red underline with Error Message - "The type or namespace name 'ContentBySearchWebPart' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

EDIT: Solution is made as farm solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick is to add reference to `Microsot.Office.Server.Search.WebControls`. However, "Add Reference..." window didn't expose this dll, so I had to manualy add it from GAC
(`C:\windows\Windows.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Server.Search`).